# Datavisualization Chart Axes dynamic location

Tags: c#, wpf

From what I see, the axis location of the charts can only be at the edges of the chart.

I need to move the x-axis so that it follows the zero-crossing of the y-axis.

I.e. if the range of values on the y-axis is -50 to +50, the x-axis will be drawn in the centre of the chart.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, it looks like the axes cannot be moved from the edges of the control.

I have found another solution to the problem by moving the axes labels which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124607/move-location-of-axis-labels-on-wpf-toolkit-chart).